# Access my own site via curl directly from webserver, but disallow access from outside

Tags: asp.net, curl, local, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-8.5

I want to use cURL from my webserver to call a page on my website (importdata.aspx) on that same webserver. But I want to make sure the importdata.aspx page can not be accessed from the internet.

I use forms authentication on my site, so I can't have the cURL call login for me.
In my web.config file I've disallowed non-authenticated users:

Setting up a different site and allowing anonymous users through IIS, still won't let me access importdata.aspx, as my formsauthentication would prevent that right?

Is there a way to allow importdata.aspx to be accessed only through the local machine and blocking it completely from outside?

Answer (score 0):

Web.config files have some options to set different configs, based on the URL path.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178692(v=vs.90).aspx

Example:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="true" timeout="10" />
  </system.web>

  <!-- Special configuration for the "importdata.aspx" -->
  <location path="importData.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Windows" /> 
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

In this example, I defined a different authentication mode for the importData.aspx file.

Comment: I get a Configuration Error: `It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.` I get this both when calling importdata.aspx through cURL from a bat file from my server as well as browsing importdata.aspx from the outside